# Passing data through from form submission depending on value

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to pass data through from a form depending on different calculations from the form submission

**Full Model**

```
    from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, date

# Create your models here.

year_choice = [
    ('year1','1-Year'),
    ('year3','3-Year')
]
weeksinyear = 52
hours = 6.5

class AdminData(models.Model):
    year1 = models.IntegerField()
    year3 = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def day_rate_year1(self):
        return self.year1 / weeksinyear / hours

    @property
    def day_rate_year3(self):
        return self.year3 / weeksinyear / hours


class Price(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contract = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=year_choice)
        start_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
        end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime(2021,3,31))
        epoch_year = date.today().year
        year_start = date(epoch_year, 1, 4)
        year_end = date(epoch_year, 3 , 31)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        @property
        def pricing(self):
            price_days = self.start_date - self.year_end
            return price_days
```

**Views**

```py
def price_detail(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = PriceForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return render(request,'confirmation.html',{'form_data': form.cleaned_data})
    else:
        form = PriceForm()


    return render(request, 'main.html', {'form': form})
```

So the idea is to change show details on the confirmation.html page depending on the contract type and start date, a basic but most like incorrect example is below:

```py
def pricingcalc(request):
    if PriceForm.contract == 'year1'
        return Price.pricing * AdminData.day_rate_year1
    else
        return Price.pricing * AdminData.day_rate_year3
```

To summarise:

- List output of values on confirmation page
- Output based on number of days x price depending on a one year contract or a three year contract.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Post your `PriceForm` definition as well. It will help. Is it a `ModelForm`? Then you can work with the created instance. But this are all assumptions until we see the form.

Comment: Modelform, added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look in documentation at how Model Forms work (more precisely [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)) we can see that once we call `.save()` on a `ModelForm` we'll get back an instance of that model.

In your case we can assume the following:

```py
if form.is_valid():
    price_instance = form.save()
```

Now, if you want to display some dynamic computed values for your pricing model, you can add a method on your `Price` model that calculates them based on `Price.contract`.

The important idea here is that once a `ModelForm` is deemed `valid` and you call `.save()` on it, this will commit by default data in your database and return an instance of that model that you can use afterwards.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense and will do some more studying on it.

Comment: I do not understand how to setup a method in the model to calculate the price, I cannot find the correct way to do it:`if self.contract == year_choice('year1')`

Comment: `if self.contract == year_choice[0][0]`. I'd recommend looking into model_utils package and Choices class :)

Comment: Alex I still cannot figure out how to pass the values across to the confirmation page and cannot figure out how to do the calculations in the model. I have spent the last 6 hours looking and my head hurts :P